# Segmentation fault , while accepting graph inputs from input file

Tags: c++, graph, stl

I am writing a program to find out **"Strongly Connected Component"** of a given graph.

For that I am using following algorithm.
1) Apply DFS and push the nodes in decreasing order of their Finishing time in stack.
2) Transpose the graph. ( reverse the edges of the graph)
3) Pop the node and apply DFS again.

For this if I accept the graph edges by function **addEdge(int u, int v)** (edge from node u to node v).
then  program works correctly.
**Question :** But when I try to accept graph through input file, it is giving me error.
I am not giving whole program as it is working correctly.

```
class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
    void fillorder( int v , bool visited[] , stack<int> &stack);
    void DFSUtil(int v , bool visited[]);    

    public:     

    Graph( int V);
    void printSCCs();
    Graph get_Transpose();
    void print_graph();
    void read_input_file();

};     


    Graph:: Graph(int V)
{
    this-> V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}
void Graph :: read_input_file()
{
   const long int N = 100;

   std::ifstream infile("S.txt"); 
   std::string line;

   int i = 0;
   while ( i < N && getline(infile, line) )
   {
      std::istringstream str(line);
      int u;

      str >> u;
      if ( u > N )
      {
         // Problem.
         abort();
      }

      int v;
      while ( str >> v )
      {
         adj[u-1].push_back(v);
      }
      ++i;
   }
}

void Graph :: print_graph()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++ )
    {
        list<int> :: iterator itr;
        for( itr = adj[i].begin(); itr != adj[i].end(); ++itr )
        {
           cout<< i+1 <<" --> " << *itr <<endl;
        }
    }
}

void Graph:: printSCCs()
{
    stack<int>Stack;
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < V ; i++ )
        visited[i] = false;

     for( int i = 0 ; i < V ; i++ )
     if(visited[i] == false)
     fillorder(i , visited , Stack);

     Graph gr = get_Transpose();

     for( int i = 0 ; i < V ; i++ )
        visited[i] = false;

        while( Stack.empty() == false)
        {

            int no = Stack.top();
            Stack.pop();
            if(visited[no] == false)
              {
              gr.DFSUtil(no , visited);
              cout<< endl;
              }
        }
}

int main()
{
    Graph g(9);
    g.read_file(); // Working perfectly
    g.print_graph(); // showing graph perfectly
    g.printSCCs(); // Giving error : Segmentation fault: core dump
    return 0;
}
```

Graph is getting printed correctly but `g.printSCCs()` is not working.

```
Error is : Segmentation fault: core dump       

Now if g.print_graph() is working perfectly then why not g.printSCCs() ?
```

NOTE :  I have not pasted whole program just to insure that it will be readable.
Moreover , by manually entering edges , whole program works perfectly , so I think there will not be error in any function.

I/P file data :

```
1 4

2 8

3 6

4 7

5 2

6 9

7 1

8 5

8 6

9 7

9 3
```

Comment: Where and how is `adj` initialized? It's not anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: it is private member of class Graph.  I have mentioned it. please check again

Comment: @Tushar can you show us where you initialize it?

Comment: I'm not asking where it's defined. I'm asking where it's initialized - given a value. Your code is using its value, but never assigning anything to it.

Comment: @Eddge  if you are talking about adj , then it is initialised in class Graph. It is it's private member.

Comment: @Tushar yes we can see it is a private datamember, but how are you initializing that private datamember?

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik : Please check, I have added initialization also.

Comment: @Tushar can you also provide a sample file that your loading in?

Comment: just a FYI your printSCC is leaking memory.

Comment: @ Eddge :   I have added sample file.

Comment: @Eddge : Then it should also leak memory if I feed input manually.

Comment: @Eddge  Can you explain what is happening exactly. Because , I need to run this program on input data which contains 90,000 nodes.

Comment: @Tushar, I am still looking into it, but yes your printSCC leaks memory without the input file as well as you are never deleting `bool* visited  = new bool[V]`  Do me a favor and make sure you are actually opening your input file, change your read_input_file to a bool type, and add a check after the infile("S.text") like `if(!infile.is_open()) return false;`  then check the return to see if it opened your file.

Comment: @Eddge : I did what you said, but getting the same error : segmentation fault( core dumped)